# Advanced LaTeX Tutorial/Book

Tags: latex

I've been using LaTeX for about 3-4 years now. In that time I've picked up what I've needed as I've needed it, most often by Googling. However, I'd like to learn some more advanced features of LaTeX such as editing or even creating my own class files and bibtex styles. I've worked with some fairly powerful class files before, but I have a tough time understanding the syntax as it's rather obscure.

Does anyone know of a good tutorial (or book) that I can use to learn such advanced features of LaTeX?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the really advanced stuff, nothing can beat the [dtx files](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=dtx) describing the LaTeX classes themselves. Your TeX distribution might not have shipped them, so get them from CTAN; the dtx files are usually stripped of comments before being installed, but you can compile them with LaTeX to get the comments and code nicely typeset.

[TUGboat](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/) has some advanced articles as well.

Comment: too true. for more advanced options nothing beats the latex package documentation. You just forgot to say that ctan normally has this documentation in pdf format that is more easy to view.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the [LaTeX Companion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321514432).

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the answers in these questions:

- [Best practices in LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193298/best-practices-in-latex)
- [What is the fastest way to learn LaTeX basics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109371/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-learn-latex-basics) (especially the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109371/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-learn-latex-basics/109682#109682) has some nice references)

Answer (score 2):

I have been using a few books over the years,

1. Guide to LaTeX by Helmut Kopka and Patrick W. Daly
2. The LaTeX Companion (Tools and Techniques for Computer Typesetting) by Frank Mittelbach, Michel Goossens, Johannes Braams and David Carlisle

And the clssic

1. LaTeX: A Document Preparation System by Leslie Lamport

Also,

1. the soft book available at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/ is a moderately good one.

Moreover, as advised above, make it a practice to read the dtx files when you start using a new style file.

Answer (score 1):

Some of these advanced topics are covered in the [Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Latex). There is also the [(Not So) Short introduction to LaTeX2e](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf).