# Good introductory tutorial on writing sty files for latex?

Tags: latex

Where do I find a good introductory tutorial on writing sty packages for latex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question comes up a lot and doesn't have a good answer. See, for example, the StackOverflow question "[Advanced LaTeX Tutorial/Book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776102/advanced-latex-tutorial-book)".

My best advice is to read lots of packages sources, clsguide.pdf (it will be in your distribution), as much of the LaTeX sources (source2e.pdf) as makes sense to you, as well as [TeX by Topic](http://www.eijkhout.net/tbt/) and any other TeX programming resources you have access to.

If you're particularly motivated you might like to read about the LaTeX3 programming bundle [expl3](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/expl3), and other such programming-related packages such as [etoolbox](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and [etextools](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/etextools), which takes quite a different approach than expl3.

Comment: I was afraid this was the case. I read the question you reference, but I was hoping there was some specific resources on writing packages for LaTeX. Thanks for your help and your references, I will be sure to check them out.